# Freshman or Freshwoman

Tags: word-choice, offensive-language, gender-neutral, political-correctness, historical-change

Can we use *freshwoman* to refer to a girl in her first year in college, or is *freshman* acceptable?

Comment: It may be in the dictionary, and there may be a slow but substantial trend brewing, but some women might still consider this a bit of an overcorrection. I don't believe any of my daughters would prefer _freshwoman_ over the more traditional alternative.

Comment: Whatever the alternatives might be for 'freshman', the term 'freshwoman' is just not used (at least in AmE).

Comment: I'd avoid referring to a female frosh as "girl."  This is a lingering bit of sexism. While high school kids are 'girls' and 'boys', college males have been 'men' for ages, so college females should be 'women.'   Then again, take a look at the FB list of gender options!

Comment: Remember that **man** is perfectly suitable for any member of *Homo sapiens* — as opposed to say *Vulpes vulpes* or *Bos taurus* — and you will see that *freshman* is the correct term for the year prior to one’s sophomore year.  Don’t let useless political correctness and hypercorrection destroy the language.

Comment: @tchrist: the language started being "destroyed" some time before the word "man" was an allowable substitute for "werman". Those trying to uniformise usage are trying to *fix* language, not break it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a slow but substantial trend of avoiding gender-specific nouns when either gender could qualify. "[Chair](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chair#Noun)" in place of "chairman/woman/person" is one example. If you wish to refer to women using terms usually reserved for men, then it's perhaps a good hint that you should start using a different term, which would include both the men and the women.

There are some explicitly gender-neutral terms for these, which for the moment are appropriate for informal speech:

- In British English: [**fresher**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fresher#Noun).
- In American English: [**frosh**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frosh#Noun_2).

In formal speech, I would tend to prefer constructions such as "first year Bachelor's student" — or just "first year" if it's clear from context.

Comment: Note that the plural of *frosh* is often *frosh*.

Answer (score 0):

We were called "freshies"--it's gender neutral.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=freshies